# I am removing timestamps from text file

Tags: regex, perl

text file contains

name of file is `clean.txt` and contents are

```
20170524201630.600|20170524201632.760|CC1|Mir wurde ganz schwer ums Herz.
20170524201633.280|20170524201634.600|CC1|Ich hoffte und betete,
```

i want to remove time stamps and output should be

```
          Mir wurde ganz schwer ums Herz.
          Ich hoffte und betete,
```

i tried running on command line

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^[1-9]\d{13}\.\d{3}\\|^[1-9]\d{13}\.\d{3}\|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]\|//g'  clean.txt
```

but I got result as it is.what is problem here ?

Comment: `\\|` should be `\|`.

Comment: I'd use `[^|]*` rather than being so precise.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

No need to read the whole file with `-0777` :

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*\|//g' file
Mir wurde ganz schwer ums Herz.
Ich hoffte und betete,
```

Or if you need to be more specific :

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(\d{14}\.\d{3}\|)+[A-Z]{2}\d+\|//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/([^CC1|]+)$//gm'  clean.txt
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1v1plG/1/).

Brief explanation:

- `([^CC1|])`
  Match a single character not present in brackets
- `\+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- `m` modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each
  line (not only begin/end of string)